# Remote sudo edit in Vim

Tags: vim, remote, editing, sudo

How can I edit a remote file with sudo?

I have ssh/scp access to remote server, and passwordless sudo on it.

I want to edit `/etc/some/file` as remote root, so I ran:

```
  $ Vi scp://server/etc/some/file
```

It doesn't work, however, citing I don't have enough permissions. How can I do this?

Comment: You can log into remote system using `ssh remoteserver`, and on remote server execute `sudo vim /etc/myfile`.  OR one command: `ssh -t remoteserver sudo vi /etc/myfile`

Comment: @taro What if he does not have a login shell on that machine?

Comment: If he does not have login, he can `scp remote:/etc/myfile ~/myfile`, edit `vim ~/myfile`, but it will be a problem to overwrite remote file with changed one.

Comment: The main aim is to use local vim (with my settings, my keymap etc) on remote. Yes, i can install on every host my settings -- but that ugly way.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem, and have the exact same motivation, to use one single central VIM program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small piece of `bash` script that does what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash -ex

TMP_FILE=$(basename "$2")

ssh -t "$1" "/bin/bash -c \"
mkdir -p /tmp/remote-sudoedit/
cd /tmp/remote-sudoedit/
/usr/bin/env SUDO_EDITOR=cat sudoedit '$2' | tee '$TMP_FILE'\""

nvim scp://"$1"//tmp/remote-sudoedit/"$TMP_FILE"

ssh -t "$1" "/bin/bash -c \"
cd /tmp/remote-sudoedit/
sudo cp '$TMP_FILE' '$2'
rm '$TMP_FILE'\""
```

Comment: Thanks -- indeed, that sounds like a closes possible option

Answer (score 0):

According [this wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip337) you should specify your username and host like that:

```
vim scp://user@server//etc/some/file
```

And thanks for the tip, I didn't know that vim is capable of editing files via scp.

Comment: Sorry, seems like it doesn't solve the problem with permissions unless you log in as root.

Comment: The problem with permissions is not a problem. If you want to do root-level stuff you just login as root, that's a good thing in my book. Your solution works well.

Comment: I have already said -- that doesn't allows to access sudo-accessible files.

Comment: And problem with permissions IS main part question. Use root-access is strictly prohibited even with key.

Comment: Remote editing in Vim is not done on the remote server. The file is downloaded locally and re-uploaded after save

Comment: I'm know. Just want to find netrw plugin/mod that allows not just scp, but ssh+sudo.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment…

Vim doesn't do that kind of fancy thing on the remote machine, no matter what account you use. It's limited to downloading and uploading: reading a remote file means downloading the file in a temporary location on your local machine, writing a remote file means uploading the local copy to the remote machine.

It means that you won't be able to `sudo` before editing on the remote machine.

If the account used to write/upload the file is not root you can't overwrite the root-owned file. That's basic UNIX/server security.

Instead, `ssh` into the server and use Vim there or use KL-7's snippet with the right account.

See `:help netrw-xfer`, and `:help netrw-quickmap` for additional features such as directory listing. No `sudo` in sight.

Comment: You can do that in emacs, his trampoline able to work via ssh+sudo. I'm just search for plugin, that implements same thing for vim.